# What are (the different aspects of) harmonic analysis good for?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, rt.representation-theory, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, fourier-analysis

Let $G$ be a locally compact group. To the best of my understanding, harmonic analysis has three legs that all work perfectly in the case that $G$ is in addition compact and abelian, but have generalizations in other cases:

1. The notion of a "dual" $\hat{G}$ (itself a topological group if $G$ is abelian, but generalizations do not require that) in such a way that $G$ is naturally isomorphic to $\hat{\hat{G}}$ and such that one has an isometry $L^2(G)\rightarrow L^2(\hat{G})$.
2. Decomposing $L^2(G)$ as a direct integral (direct sum in the case that $G$ is compact) of irreducible unitary representations.
3. Coming up with a simultaneous eigenbasis (w.r.t the $G$ action) for $L^2(G)$ (in the case that $G$ is compact).

Perhaps this is because I don't have any engineering background, but it's difficult for me to tell what each (or even any!) of these legs of harmonic analysis are actually good for.

#### Question

For each of the above "legs of harmonic analysis" *separately*: why is such a result desirable, and what can it be naturally applied towards in order to solve? What makes these results interesting other than for their own sake?

Of course I know about Langlands, and the great benefits to the world of number theory of ideas coming from representation theory. But I'm looking for much more basic applications than that...

Comment: What does $\hat{\hat G}$ mean in the situations where $\hat G$ is not a topological group?

Comment: Wavelet transform? Spherical harmonics?

Comment: To try and get a better idea of what you are looking for: do you feel that for each of the above, you have seen results and applications in the **abelian case** which answer your questions? If not, then that would be a natural issue to address first

Comment: Point 1) is very useful to diagonalise important differential and integral operators, and thus to solve differential and integral equations (for instance, for the additive group $G = \mathbb{R}^d$, but also in cases such as $G = \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ with multiplication). If I remember correctly, Fourier invented the whole topic (in a special case, of course) in order to solve the heat equation.

Comment: At an undergraduate-level, I have used (3) in solving PDEs... Did I use (1) and (2)? I don't think I did...?

Comment: @JochenGlueck I must confess I interpreted the question as mainly being about the non-abelian setting, because in the abelian setting I had the impression that the Fourier transform's utlity would be familiar from things typically seen in UG courses (ODE, PDE, probability theory ...)

Comment: @JochenGlueck, that sounds like a use of (3), no?

Comment: Well in 1) you have combined Pontrjagin duality and the Parseval formula / Plancherel theorem. The latter is a fairly fundamental fact even for the dual pair T and Z which has natural physical interpretations in terms of energy, although I admit I can't think of direct applications per se outside of pure maths

Comment: @YemonChoi, yes it is mostly about the non-abelian and/or the non-compact case, but the answer should be from an understanding of why the different legs are useful for different things in the abelian case.

Comment: @AndrewNC: On compact intervals yes. If we want to solve the heat equation $\dot u = \Delta u$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$, there is no eigenbasis, though (in the literal sense of a Hilbert space ONB); but we can apply that the Fourier transform from $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ to $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ intertwines the Laplace operator with the mulitplication by $-x^2$. This is one way to compute the heat kernel of $\dot u = \Delta u$.

Comment: I suppose I am just trying to figure out what _you_ feel harmonic analysis on abelian groups might be useful for, or connected to, before trying to dive into the technical complications of the non-abelian setting. For the abelian setting I recommend getting hold of a copy of Korner's "Fourier Analysis"

Comment: BTW character theory of finite non-abelian groups seems like an "application" of 2) to me, if when you ask "what can it be naturally applied towards in order to solve?" you are including applications to other areas of "pure" mathematics

Comment: @YemonChoi: I see. Yes, I agree that the classical applications of the Abelian case are typically covered in undergraduate courses (although it might depend a bit on the individual choice of courses: quite embarrasingly, I somehow managed to completely avoid solving any PDE via the Fourier transform until I started my PhD...).